# 2 virtual interfaces on the same vlan

Tags: vlan, bridge

I have one vlan with id 30. The VLAN interface on the host is `eno1.30`. I need two bridges to access this VLAN. Can I create a new virutal interface on the same VLAN in the same machine and add the second one to the bridge? How to achieve this? IP aliasing doesn't allow me to connect it two bridges.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is your setup? Can you make a graphic or something? I don't get it from your 3 lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

With two interfaces to the same segment/VLAN, both interfaces require different IP addresses.

Alternatively, (with host support) you can bond both interfaces into a single logical interface. How this bonding is done and which options you have (active/passive, MAC failover, ...) depends on the host. Several bonding methods are not reliable when both links terminate on different switches/bridges. Bonded interfaces do not usually bridge traffic (which would likely create a bridge loop on a switch).